# log4j create new log file every time logger.info() method is called

Tags: java, log4j

I have a request to implement a java application with log4j. The logger should always create a new logfile every time I call log4j method info() or one of the others. Iam not getting it to work. The log file name should be like this:
IB.YYMMdd.IncrementNumber

Pattern could also be like this IB.YYMMddhhmmss (Date with milliseconds).

I've implemented a CustomFileAppender which did not work.

My messages are always written in the same log file per java run. But I want new log file every time the info method is called.

Is there a possibility to achieve my goal with log4j.

My current java code:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class Log4jTest {

    static {

           SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("YYMMddhhmmss");
            System.setProperty("current.date.time", dateFormat.format(new Date()));
    }

    final static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Log4jTest.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        log.info("Message 1");
        Thread.sleep(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(2));
        log.info("Message 2");
    }
}
```

My log4jproperties file:

```
log4j.rootLogger=ALL, stdout, file
logDir = C:\\temp

# Redirect logs to console
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Redirect logs to a file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=${logDir}/IB.${current.date.time}.log
log4j.appender.file.append=false
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Thx in advance.

BR, Sandro

Comment: With your current code, the application will create a new log file every time it is restarted. I suggest using DailyRollingFileAppender which will create a log file for a day.

Comment: Thx for your answer, but i do not need a logfile per day. I need a logfile when ever info() method or other LogLevel method is called.